# Admob Banner add not working with ListView in layout

Tags: android, listview, banner-ads

banner ad not displaying.when used together with Listview
my code//

```
AdView mAdView = (AdView) findViewById(R.id.adView);
AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().build();
mAdView.loadAd(adRequest);
```

Xml code for activity

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
        android:id="@+id/adView"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        ads:adSize="BANNER"
        ads:adUnitId="@string/banner_ad_unit_id"/>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" >
    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/list"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"/>

    </RelativeLayout>
   </LinearLayout>
```

please help to find a solution 
All other activities works fine with this code

Comment: You relativeLayout is overlaying the adView...it´s match parent....

Comment: Thanks for the reply.changed it to "wrap_content" but not working

Comment: made a clean and rebuild your project?

Comment: i did that but no use

Answer (score 0):

Add Like Below

```
    <LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants">


    <com.twotoasters.jazzylistview.JazzyListView
        android:id="@+id/listview"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:scrollbars="none"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        app:effect="cards"
        app:max_velocity="0"
        app:only_animate_fling="false"
        app:only_animate_new_items="false" />

</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/linin"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    >

    <com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
        android:id="@+id/adViewList"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        ads:adSize="SMART_BANNER"
        ads:adUnitId="@string/banner" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add like below

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:id="@+id/activity_main"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:background="@drawable/back"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/toolbar"
        android:clipToPadding="false"
        android:paddingBottom="50dp">

     <ListView
         android:id="@+id/list"
         android:layout_width="match_parent"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:layout_margin="5dp"/>

    </LinearLayout>

<com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
    android:id="@+id/main_bottom_banner"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    ads:adSize="BANNER"
    ads:adUnitId="@string/main_banner_ad_unit_id">
</com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView>

</RelativeLayout>
```